# JAVA moving a ball

Tags: java, swing

I have tried to make a program that on the screen the ball would move by itself. But the problem is that it doesn`t do repaint();

Any suggestion how to fix it?

(main class) Main.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    static int x = 10;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("title");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(300,250);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sekon m = new sekon();
        f.add(m);

        antr t = new antr();
        Thread th = new Thread(t);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

(second class) sekon.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class sekon extends JPanel{
    int xiu = 10;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(xiu, 10, 20, 20);

    }


    public void changeX(int b){
        this.xiu = b;
    }



}

     class antr extends JPanel implements Runnable{
         int xi = 10;
        sekon s = new sekon();
         public void run(){

             xi += 1;
             s.changeX(xi);
             JPanel p = new JPanel();
             p.repaint();

             try{
                 Thread.sleep(5);
                 }catch(Exception e){}
         }
    }
```

Comment: 1) `Thread.sleep(5);`  Don't block the EDT.  Call the method from a Swing `Timer`. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 4) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

1) in your code is `repaint()` blocked by code line `Thread.sleep(5);`

2) you code doesn't work, because missed ..., all coordinates for moving `Oval` throught the screen

3) for Swing container, Swing JComponent use only [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for dealying, moving, repainting,

sure is possible by using `Runnable#Thread`, but not this way,

example about `Swing Timer`

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class AnimationJPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int cx = 0;
        private int cy = 150;
        private int cw = 20;
        private int ch = 20;
        private int xinc = 1;
        private int yinc = 1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AnimationJPanel panel = new AnimationJPanel();
                    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                    panel.animate();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public AnimationJPanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This is an AnimationJPanel");
            label.setForeground(Color.RED);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            add(label);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setForeground(Color.RED);
            setOpaque(true);
        }

        public void animate() {
            new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Rectangle oldCircle = new Rectangle(cx - 1, cy - 1, cw + 2, ch + 2);
                    cx += xinc;
                    cy += yinc;
                    if (cx >= getWidth() - cw || cx <= 0) {
                        xinc *= -1;
                    }
                    if (cy >= getHeight() - ch || cy <= 0) {
                        yinc *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint(oldCircle);
                    repaint(cx - 1, cy - 1, cw + 2, ch + 2);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawOval(cx, cy, cw, ch);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance of `sekon` owned by the `antr` object is distinct from the one added to the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Study the following instructional example to see how to cause repaint animation.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
new JFrame("AnimationStudy") {
  int    x = 0;
  JPanel j = new JPanel() {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(x, 10, 20, 20);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawChars(("" + x).toCharArray(), 0, ("" + x).length(), x, 10);
    }
  };
  {
    setSize(300, 100);
    setLocation(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(j);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        int t = 250;
        for (x = 10; x < t; x += 1) {
          j.repaint();
          try {
            Thread.sleep((t - x) / 4);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }).start();
  }
};
}
```

Comment: Also consider `javax.swing.Timer`; see also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1):

See the example
http://java-sl.com/tip_flatteningpathiterator_moving_shape.html

Answer (score 0):

Your class antr and the main class use different instances of sekon. You should probably pass the instance created in the main method to the antr class.